# cordova admobpro plugin refresh entire page when loaded first time

Tags: javascript, cordova, admob, ionic-framework

English is not my first language, feel free to ask me any question to clarify this problem.

Im using [admobpro](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) plugin for my `ionic/cordova` apps.

This is the code i used for displaying the banner ads :

```
if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
} else {
    initApp();
}

function initApp() {

    AdMob.createBanner( {
        adId: admobid.banner, 
        isTesting: false,
        overlap: false, 
        offsetTopBar: false, 
        position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER//,
        //bgColor: 'yellow'
    } );

}
```

The problem is the entire page where the banner displayed will be reloaded/refreshed the first time the banner displayed. This will result in a blink to the page.

Is there any way to display the banner fluently? (without any blink)

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: me too facing the same problem..  Did you get a solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: same here. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the AdMob cordova plugin.

I don't know if the plugin was updated recently to fix the problem.

Anyway, one proposed solution (may be not robust 100% but very helpful) is to keep the splash screen displayed until the banner had been fully displayed for a moment.

Pseudo code:

```
banner.create().then(()=>{
   setTimeout(()=>{
      splashScreen.hide();
   }, 200);
});
```